# Inconsistent Connection to Site (Apache, Nextcloud,OpenCMS)

Tags: apache, nextcloud, opencms

So I'm pretty new to the server and website dev. Self "taught".

I recently setup a home server running Apache on Ubuntu 20.04(MicroK8s, Linux Server). Postgres database. Nextcloud Cloud server. TomCat and OpenCMS system. And Postfix.

I have a domain name pointing to my address. When I'm home, i.e. physically near my server. And I connect to my subdomain. Cloud.example.com I get nextcloud. When I connect to the 8080 port([www.example.com:8080](http://www.example.com:8080)) I get tomcat and OpenCMS. So far, so good.

When I use a VPN, or am not near my server, and go to the subdomain,I *sometimes* get one of those random "ad" sites that says "this site may be able to purchase".

After more testing it seems like the number of connected users also changes whether I get the rando site or the intended one.

My server is... Old. Likely slow (4GBram and a Core 2 Duo, it's the fastest old tower I had laying around). So I *think* it's a timeout error within OpenCMS, that serves a rando site when it can't get nextcloud to respond fast enough. But honestly, I'm not even sure where to start, or what to even ask/say or what you would need to see to even start diagnostic...

When I connect to mydomain.com from the vpn i get a 404. Which makes sense, as I haven't built it yet in OpenCMS.

Any pointers on where to start?

What am I missing?

Do I need to delete my /var/www sites or Virtual Hosts, and let OpenCMS handle all the routing?

I'm confused as to how my server knows to point 8080 to tomcat/OpenCMS, as I never setup a virtual host. How will it eventually know to point mydomain.com to the sites I build in OpenCMS? Or will OpenCMS deploy them to /var/www? Will I need to transfer the netcloud site to the OpenCMS directory?

I know this is a lot of free help to ask for, but I'm doing this mostly for fun and to learn, and don't have anyone who knows. I don't want to pay it out as I'd rather learn it. I'm not even sure where to start asking, but have browsed stack overflow for **A LOT** of excel, Apache, Linux, and other answers in the past, so thought I would ask here first.

Comment: You write a lot of text, but almost no steps to reproduce (e.g. your specific setup). As it is - and according to the tags' descriptions - I'm tempted to remove the [tag:linux] and  [tag:apache] tags (please read their descriptions). Please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve] (by editing your quetion with the steps to reproduce - e.g. your setup)

Comment: Thanks for helping me refine my question. I will remove the linux tag, though this might be an Apache thing so I'd like to leave that. Though I'm not sure how else to explain how to reproduce than I already have. I go to my domain. Sometimes it goes where I think it should, sometimes it doesn't. Most often, when it doesn't, I'm farther from home. I'm also not even sure what else you need to know about my setup. I've provided the relevant programs and apps I'm using. subdomain setup. What am I missing?